# Removing duplicates and summing their values into a single row - Excel Reporting

Tags: sql, excel, filter, grouping, reporting

So I would like to get this table to only display 1 row for each individual with a sum of all of their tickets. The way it is right now, Marci is coming up multiple times because each row represents the amount of tickets for a different department (Ex. # of paramedic tickets, # of FireFighter tickets, etc..) I tried the "Unique Records Only" under the advanced tab, and obviously that didn't work because the rows are not unique.

[image]

Can someone please assist me?

Comment: Since Pivot tables summarize by unique records, your data is the issue. MARCI is likely repeating because the actual text in the data has various numbers of trailing spaces. Try creating another column in the data that uses the `TRIM` function to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: How is SQL related to the question?

Comment: Seeing the SQL tag, if you are pulling data using SQL you can re-write your SQL query to remove the leading and trailing spaces so that you don't have to do it in Excel

Comment: where would I rewrite the query? within management studio? or is there a way to manipulate the connected data source in excel?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you referring to when you say "leading and trailing spaces", I just want to solve the duplication and sum the totals of said duplications into a single row.

Comment: @QuestionQuestion, you can modify the query by editing the connections of your workbook.  You can find them on the Data tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need VBA. Make a loop on these 2 concepts:
1: sort cells alphabetically
1: check neighbour cells for equality:
2: Delete and number occurences if true
3: proceed to read next line

```
Sub RemoveAndNumberDuplicates
    Dim r As range
        Set r = Selection
        for N=1 to 100
           IF r.offset(N, 0).value= R.offset(N - 1 - NumOfDeletedLines, 0).value  THEN
             SumOfDupl=SumOfDupl+1 'number of current record instances
             rang.offset(N, 0).Delete (xlShiftUp)
             rang.offset(N, 1).Value=SumOfDupl ' show duplicates in side column
             NumOfDeletedLines=NumOfDeletedLines+1 'needed to correct offset for deleted lines
           Else 
             SumOfDupl=1'restart numbering if no duplicate found
           End If
        Next N
End Sub
```

This is a general idea for Excel VBA, not a complete code.

Comment: I have never worked with VBA. Visual basic im assuming, but how would I go about obtaining VBA?

Comment: It is allready included in Excel and open office. Press Alt+F11 and there you go. See some tutorials for Excel VBA